# Listen for callbacks in dotNetBrowser

Tags: winforms, httplistener, dotnetbrowser

How can I use dotnetbrowser doing the following in a winform application?

- Create a listener that listen for callbacks to a specific redirect url.
- Open url in dotnetbrowser. The url makes the callback to the redirect url in another thread
- The listener catches the response from the callback.

I can do this with an ordinary webbrowser, but I would like it to be silent. That's why I try to use dotnetbrowser instead.

Is dotNetBrowser a good choice for this, or is there a better option?

This is from my test code with a non silent webbrowser. First I create a listener that listen to a redirectUri:

```
        var listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(redirectURI);
        listener.Start();
```

Then I start the url in a webbrowser:

```
        Process p = Process.Start(url);
```

The started url will send a callback to the redirectUri. The listener will get it.

```
        var context = await listener.GetContextAsync(); ;
        string formData = string.Empty;
        using (var body = context.Request.InputStream)
        {
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, context.Request.ContentEncoding))
            {
                formData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        listener.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution with help from dotnetbrowser support site.

This is the winform constructor in my new test project:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        webView = new BrowserView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            engine = EngineFactory.Create(new EngineOptions.Builder
            {
                RenderingMode = RenderingMode.HardwareAccelerated,
                LicenseKey = "your license key here"
            }
            .Build());
            browser = engine.CreateBrowser();
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            webView.InitializeFrom(browser);

            var listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add(redirectURI);
            listener.Start();

            browser.Navigation.LoadUrl(url);

            var context = listener.GetContextAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            //Get data from redirectUri. You find this code from test example above, but not really relevant for the problem.
            var formData = GetRequestPostData(context.Request);
            listener.Close();

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        InitializeComponent();
        FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
        Controls.Add(webView);

        this.Visible = false;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        browser?.Dispose();
        engine?.Dispose();
    }
```